# Most middleware (like staticCache) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have installed the [suggested](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware) modules, but I am still getting the same issue whenever I try to serve a directory with httpster

Comment: You at least need to show in your question (1) a sample of the modules you are using, (2) the error messages you are getting, and (3) what have you done so far to fix the problem..

Comment: @TeeKea Its only Httpster installed globally so far, I have also installed the suggested modules in the link, but I have no idea how to connect them